# Solve first order differential equation boundary value problem using Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve a model of a physical structure with the following equation:

> $y'(x) + \frac{-ax+b}{-x^2+x+m}y(x) + \frac{k}{-x^2+x+m}=0$

The boudnary condition is:

> y(0) = -y(1)

where $a = 160$, $b = 6500$, $m = 30$ and $k = 700$ are positive constants.
I am only interested in [0, 1].

I have tried to put it into Matlab Mupad or Wolframalpha; however, the solution could not be described as elementary mathematics (it showed something as hypergeometric function).  I would like to look at the solution numerically.  Since this is not an initial value problem, I do not think ode45 is a good solver in this case.  I have googled bvp4c - boundary value problem solver of Matlab.  Unfortunately, all of them are about two-point second order ODE.  I wonder if someone can give me a hint or guidance how to do it. The preferred software is Matlab, but I am fine with other software also.

Comment: What are the values of your constants? Also, are you missing part of the boundary condition details?

Comment: I did put it in text.  I have made it clearer now and added the values of the constants.

Comment: $y(0) = y(-1) = ~?$

Comment: In this case $y(0)=-y(1)$ is not an admissible boundary condition, because the solution is of the form $y(x)=f(x)+C$, so $y(0)=-y(1)$ either happens as a result of the equation or it doesn't. Is it possible that there is a $y$ in your ODE that you have incorrectly written as $x$?

Comment: Either you have a typo in your question or what you entered into Matlab Mupad and Wolfram alpha is different from the system in your question (or maybe you used the wrong code). The analytic solution to your BVP involves nothing more than `log` (even if all of your variables are left as symbolic).

Comment: @Ian I disagree with $y(x)=f(x)+C$.  Instead, for first order DE, it should be $y(x) = g(x) + C f(x)$.

Comment: @horchler I know the result in such a way; however, as I said, I was modeling a physical structure, thus, those are time-independent constants, but geometry dependent parameters.  I would not prefer to keep typing that long formula in every time I change the geometry of my structure.

Comment: @Cuong It is true that $y(x)=g(x)+Cf(x)$, except $f(x)$ is a homogeneous solution, which here is trivially seen to be constant (the homogeneous equation is $y'=0$). So again, I suspect you have incorrectly written the differential equation you wish to solve.

Comment: I don't agree with the assessment $y(0)=-y(1)$ is not an admissible condition. OK, If the condition was $y(0)=y(1)$ it would be not admissible because the integration constant $C$ could not be computed. But with $y(0)=-y(1)$ we can analytically express $C$ which determines $y(0)$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, it is a mistake. I missed the y(x) in the equation. Thank you for correcting me. I just edit it.

Comment: @JJacquelin Good point, still, I turned out to be right anyway.

Comment: @Ian. Since the differential equation has changed after my answer, what I did has become obsolete and my comments too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ODE was changed after my preceeding answer, I open a second answer, but I don't suppress the first one because it is anyways a interesting exercise.

I have not MATLAB at hand but any other soft for numerical solving of differential equation can be used with the method below.

One can see that $y'=0$ when $(-ax+b)y+k=0$ , hense $y=-\frac{k}{-ax+b}$ . With the example of data and for $0<x<1$, the values of $y(x)$ for $y'=0$ are in the range $-\frac{700}{-160+6500} < y < -\frac{700}{6500}$.

If we start with a value of $y(0)$ not too far from these values, after $y(x)$ comes at the point where $y'=0$ then $y(x)$ remains constant.

So, the process is very simple : Set $y(0)= -\frac{700}{6500}$ for example (other values not too far would lead to almost the same result). The numerical calculus gives $y(1)=-0.110397$ .  This is already close to $-y(0)$

In order to obtain a better accuracy, restart the numerical calculus with $y(0)=0.110397$ . The result is $y(1)=-0.11039691$ . This is the wanted result $y(1)\simeq -y(0)$.

The graphical representation of the calculus of $y(x)$ is shown on the next figure :

[image]

Only the part of the curve for low values of $x$ is represented since $y(x)$ remains constant up to $x=1$.

An elementary algorithm :

[image]

The time of computation and drawing the curve $y(x)$ is less than 1 second on an ordinary PC.

Answer (score 2):

Analytic solution :
$$y(x)=-\int \frac{-ax+b+k}{-x^2+x+m} = \frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) - \frac{a}{2}\ln|-x^2+x+m | +C$$

With condition $y(0)=-y(1)$ :

$y(0)=\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) - \frac{a}{2}\ln|m | +C$

$C=y(0)-\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) + \frac{a}{2}\ln|m|$

$$y(x)=y(0)-\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) + \frac{a}{2}\ln|m|+  +{\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) - \frac{a}{2}\ln|-x^2+x+m |} $$

As a consequence :

$y(1)=y(0)-\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) + \frac{a}{2}\ln|m| + {\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) - \frac{a}{2}\ln|m|} $

$y(1)=y(0)+2\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right)$

The second condition $y(1)=-y(0)$  implies :

$-y(0)=y(0)+2\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right)$

$y(0)=-\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right)$

$$y(x)=-2\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) + \frac{a}{2}\ln|m|+ +{\frac{a-2b-2k}{\sqrt{4m+1} }\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{4m+1}} \right) - \frac{a}{2}\ln|-x^2+x+m |} $$

Comment: I made a mistake in the equation. The analytical solution is not this simple. That is why I am looking for numerical solution. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Matlab code to solve this problem. It's basically a shooting method that uses root-finding to find the appropriate initial condition. There is no guarantee that such an initial condition exists, and if it does, whether or not it would be unique.

The first part of the code defines the ODE you want to solve:

```
a=160
b=6500
m=30
k=700
der=@(x,y) ((-a*x+b).*y+k)./(x.^2-x-m);
```

Now set up some code that, when given a value for $y(0)$, solves the ODE and returns $y(0)$ and $y(1)$.

```
f=@(T) T.y([1 end]);
sol=@(y0) f(ode45(der,[0 1],y0));
```

Use the Matlab builtin `fzero` function to find when $y(0)+y(1)=0$,

```
Y0=fzero(@(y0) sum(sol(y0)),0.5)
```

and use that $y(0)$ to solve the ODE properly and plot the solution:

```
[x,y]=ode45(der,[0 1],Y0);
plot(x,y)
```

This gave me $y(0)=0.11037$ and $y(-1)=-0.11037$.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  However, JJacquelin provided a more details.  I also upvote your answer, by the way.